# Doubts in a proof showing that $\sup \{x\in \Bbb{Q}: x>0, x^2 <2 \}= \sqrt{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand the following proof:

> [image]

> [image]

I don't understand why they assume $(s-\frac{1}{n})^2 <2$ "so quickly" but when it comes to $(s+\frac{1}{n})^2$, they first suppose that $(s+\frac{1}{n})^2<2$, obtain a contradiction and then obtain that $(s+\frac{1}{n})^2 \geq 2$. Is there a reason why we don't need to suppose $(s-\frac{1}{n})^2 >2$?

Comment: Well, as they say, $s-\frac 1n$ isn't an upper bound for $A$.  That means there is some element in $A$ which is greater than $s-\frac 1n$, and that's all you need.

Comment: @lulu But $s+1/n$ is an upper bound, right? How could we have that $(s+\frac{1}{n})^2<2$?

Comment: And that's what they point out.  I think you are just objecting to the author's asymmetric style.

Comment: Ah, I see the point of confusion.  The issue is that, just because we have some number $N>s$ we don't instantly know that $N^2≥2$ since $N$ might be irrational.  If it were rational, we'd be done instantly since then $N$ would be in $A$ and we'd have this from the upper bound property.  This doesn't matter on the other side, since we can find an element of $A$ between the given value and $s$.  Knowing that the rationals are dense in the reals the point is easily settled, but of course the author is trying to construct the reals so can't use this fact.  So they need to make a specific argument.

Comment: Can you tell me the book which the question comes from?

Comment: @Tim Kaczor/Nowak's Problems in Mathematical Analysis I.

Comment: @lulu I guess that with your help, I figured out what is happening. We have the following information:

$$s-\frac{1}{n}<s \qquad A<s \qquad A^2 < s^2 \qquad A^2 <2$$

The first and second inequality and the fact that $s=\sup A$ solve my first doubt. And just by looking at the third and fourth inequalities, we don't imediately know whether: 

$$s^2 <2 \qquad  2 < s^2 \qquad s^2=2$$

We just know that both $s^2$ and $2$ are larger than any element in $A^2$ but this doesn't show where they stand with respect to one another. Thank you very much!